# For com o mesmo valor da ultima vez que foi utilizado

Tags: java, android

Como faço para que o valor do `contador` do `for` comece com o mesmo valor da última vez que foi utilizado? Porque este `for` sempre começa quando eu inicio a `activity`, e preciso que ele não comece do 1 cada vez que inicio a `activity`, que são muitas vezes, porque assim vai me adicionar valores a mais na `ArrayList`.

```
   for(int contador = 1 ;contador<=myDB.getLastId();contador++){

        testes.add("Data:  "+myDB.getDates(contador)+"        "+myDB.getHour(contador)+"\n"+"Discilpina:  "+myDB.getDisciplina(contador));


    }
```

Comment: Por que o `adapter` está dentro do `for`?! Tem alguma coisa errada ai que não está certa.

Comment: Ja tirei o adapter de dentro do for e continua a repetir o for. Porque este ciclo for começa quando a activity é indicada , que por acaso, é muitas vezes por isso á ArrayList testes vai estar sempre a estar adicionados valores

Comment: Eu queria que o valor do contador se mantive-se constante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver isso é utilizar `SharedPreferences` para salvar o número do seu contador. Primeiro instancie:

```
SharedPreferences config = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = config.edit();
```

Depois na parte do `for` eu substituiria por um `do while` e pegaria o valor salvo nas `SharedPreferences` para realizar o laço. Ficaria assim:

```
int contador = config.getInt("contador", 1);

  do {
      testes.add("Data:  "+myDB.getDates(contador)+"        "+myDB.getHour(contador)+"\n"+"Discilpina:  "+myDB.getDisciplina(contador));
      contador++;
    } while (contador<=myDB.getLastId());

editor.putInt("contador", contador);
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,testes);
testList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Observe que antes do `do-while` é obtido o contador salvo e caso não haja nenhum é pego o número`1`. Depois é salvo o valor do contador através do `editor`. E como o acklay comentou, retire o `adapter` de dentro do laço.

Talvez fosse melhor utilizar uma variável estática com o contador ou mudar a arquitetura de seu projeto para uma maneira mais sistemática mas isso que passei deve resolver.

Comment: Não resolveu , continua a fazer o do while uma vez do(do o para myDB.getLastID())  inicio e depois quando esta activity é iniciada de novo faz o do while do 0 para o myDB.getLastID() outra vez

Comment: Eu fiz com static so que o problema é que quando eu saia da activity e voltava a abrir ela não executava porque o valor do contador era igual a myDB.getLastID()

Comment: O `myDB.getLastID()` começa em 0? Tente mudar o contador para começar com 0 `int contador = config.getInt("contador", 0);`. O `SharedPreferences` mantém o valor salvo mesmo fechando o app.

Comment: Tente também printar os valores do `myDB.getLastID()` para ver se estão certos.