# Salvar frase na TextView ao fechar o app

Tags: android, array, textview

Tenho muitas frases que serão exibidas em uma TextView, ao passo que vou clicando no botão vai surgindo novas frases, queria saber se da frase que está no indice 0, ao clicar ela for para indice 1, se eu fechar o app e abrir novamente quero que fique onde ficou ao fechar, no indice 1

Comment: SharedPreferences

Comment: Veja se essa a resposta [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221389/for-com-o-mesmo-valor-da-ultima-vez-que-foi-utilizado/221400#221400) ou [dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25167/salvar-valor-em-sharedpreference) te ajuda.

Comment: SharedPrefences? Desculpe, teria como você especificar melhor? pois estou acostumado a pegar um valor da EditText e então salva-la a partir daí, nunca fiz com frases de Array já definidas

Answer (score 0):

Para ajudar segue exemplo usando SharedPreferences que peguei de um projeto meu:

```
        public static final String MY_PREFS = "MEUAPP";
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear(); // No teu caso pode retirar o clear, eh que eu precisava que começasse vazio
        editor.apply();
        // Utilizo esse objeto collegeData pq estou pegando a informação de um retorno json, mas vc pode utilizar um TextView ali
        editor.putInt("id", Integer.parseInt(collegeData.getString("id")));
        editor.putString("nome", collegeData.getString("nome"));
```

Para pegar a info que vc salvou anteriormente é só declarar o SharedPreferences novamente na Activity que vc quer.

```
        public static final String MY_PREFS = "MEUAPP";
        TextView name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nome_menu);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        name.setText(prefs.getString("nome", null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa sobrescrever o método onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState), neste método você deve colocar o valor da sua variável que armazena o índice, segue o exemplo:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MeuIndice", suaPropriedadeQueArmazenaOIndice);
}
```

No onCreate, você consegue recuperar o dado, sempre que aplicação retorna ele volta para o método onCreate, segue o exemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.telainicial);

        suaPropriedadeQueArmazenaOIndice = savedInstanceState.getInt("MeuIndice");
    }
```

Comment: está dando erro, quando boto para rodar, diz o aplicativo parou, será que não está faltando o onRestoreInstanceState?